# How to make null knowing link

Tags: java

I have next method

```
public Event findEvent(Date date){
        for (int i = 0; i < events.length ; i++) {
            if(events[i].getDate() == date){
                return events[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

It returns me link from object in array.
Then I want to delete this element, but don't know how to correct code it.

```
public void deleteEvent(Date date){
        findEvent(date) = null; //??????????? 
        Event[] list = new Event[events.length - 1];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < events.length ; i++) {
            if(events[i] != null){
                list[j] = events[i];
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `==` to compare Date (or any type of) objects

Comment: @cricket_007 what do you mean?

Comment: You should use List for this instead of array then you can easily remove an item

Comment: `==` is not comparing what you think it is

Comment: Return the index instead of the reference allowing you to set the reference at the index to null.

Comment: Since no one wants to actually help you out here, `==` is used to compare the value that is directly stored in a variable. Only primitive variables like `int`, `double`, `char`, etc will directly store their value in the variable. An object reference variable directly stores the memory location of its object, so even if two object references are both pointing to separate but equal objects, using `==` on them will return false since the two objects exist in different locations. To compare objects you must use the `equals` method from the `Object` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the found event to compare against, if no event was found for the date then just return with nothing changed.

```
public void deleteEvent(Date date){
    Event foundEvent = findEvent(date);

    if (foundEvent == null) {
        return;
    }

    Event[] list = new Event[events.length - 1];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < events.length ; i++) {
        if(!events[i].getDate().equals(foundEvent.getDate())) {
            list[j] = events[I];
            j++;
        }
    }
    events = list;
}
```

Comment: This is assuming equals and hashcode are implemented correctly on the Event class

Comment: Oh, it it the closest solution. But will we have occupied memory with old array or it will be cleared?

Comment: @cricket_007, yes it does but I am not sure why I am not using the getDate() method which would be safer. Thanks, I fixed that just to be safe.

Comment: @AndreyKompaniets, the old events version will be garbage collected.

Comment: Looks better, though `foundEvent.getDate()` should just be `date`

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value to a method return value.

While, yes, you logically want to "set the found date to null", you will need to actually do that within the loop

And instead of setting it to null, you could skip over its index and not copy it into the new list

```
public void deleteEvent(Date date){
    Event[] list = new Event[events.length - 1];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < events.length ; i++) {
        if(events[i] != null){
            if (events[i].getDate().equals(date)) continue; // skip the event to delete 
            list[j] = events[i];
            j++;
        }
    }
    events = list;  // reassign the new events 
}
```

Note: this doesn't work if multiple events are on the same date

---

Alternatively, make the find method return an index

```
public int findEvent(Date date){
    for (int i = 0; i < events.length ; i++) {
        if(events[i].getDate().equals(date)){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

From which you can delete

```
int indexToRemove = findEvent(date);
if (indexToRemove > 0) {
    events[indexToRemove] = null;
    // copy these events to new list to remove nulls
}
```

---

If you're not required to use arrays, you should be using an Arraylist and making your Event objects as Comparable types

Comment: and I don't need the method that returns the link on object (first) for delete?

Comment: I don't know your assignment, but I would like to think you're still required to implement a method to find an Event